# Problem with mysqli_real_escape_string (and magic quotes is off)

Tags: mysqli

I am having a problem with mysqli_real_escape_string and single quotes.

Anytime an insert takes a value that includes a ' mysqli_real_escape_string replaces it with \' causing the insert to fail.

I do not have magic quotes enabled, which seems to be a common cause of this problem, but still find I get \' and not \' or even \\'

Can anyone tell me what might have gone wrong here?

Comment: I should also mention that it escapes other things fine. A " becomes \" as expected and a \ becomes \\

Comment: I fail to see any difference between your \' and \' in the "I do not have" paragraph? Can you show a sample query where this is happening? The escape function's job is to escape any character which is 'meta' in SQL. Generally that's `\ ' "` to name the "big 3"

Comment: Didn't realise that would happen. When I wrote a double \ the second one has been removed.

The difference I mean is that I get \ \ ' not \ ' or \ \ \ ' (minus the spaces)

A sample query would be something like:
$query = "INSERT INTO `test` ( `test`.`a` , `test`.`b` ) VALUES ( '$a' , '$b' );
where $a and $b have been escaped and can contain a '

Comment: So you're dealing with partially escaped data already? Backslashes are escaped but quotes aren't? You have have to massage things with `strip_slashes()` before doing the proper escape_string call.

Comment: By escaped I meant $a and $b have been passed through mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @mattm591: Sounds like you might be escaping twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking this to an answer since comments are a bit limiting.

So you're generating the query like

```
$a = mysqli_real_escape_string(... something ...);
$b = mysqli_real_escape_string(... something else ...);

$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('$a', '$b')";
```

?

---

ok. so let's say this:

```
$a = "'"; // a is now a single quote: '
$escaped_a = mysql_real_escape_string($a); // should be \' now

$sql1 = "INSERT ... VALUES ('$a' ..."
$sql2 = "INSERT ... VALUES ('$escaped_a' ..."
```

you should end up with

```
INSERT ... vALUES (''' ...
INSERT ... VALUES ('\'' ...
```

The first one is "bad". because of the extra quote. The second is valid.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem them. Have you compared the a/b vars before/after escaping? It is possible magic quotes are still on because you turned them off  in the wrong place, or a later directive overrode your setting.

Comment: Well this is strange. The value is simply ' before mysqli_real_escape_string. After calling the function the value becomes \'
It seems to only be when the query is then prepared that the additional \ appears.
Any ideas why that might happen? I'm running the query with the format:
mysqli_query( $db , "INSERT ... VALUES ( '$a' , '$b' )" );

Comment: You're right. The problem wasn't the query, it was my own forgetfulness. I discovered that I'd put in a preg_replace to escape ' earlier in the code. When I came back to edit it and add the mysqli_real_escape_string() I forgot that I'd done this. Thanks for taking the time to answer! Sorry it was a bit of a waste of time.